# Is it relevant to check network capabilities if I specified them in the network request

Tags: android, kotlin, android-networking, android-connectivitymanager

In my code, I need to track the internet connection and make appropriate changes. First of all, I create a network request, then register a network callback using the `ConnectivityManager`.

```
    val networkCallback = createNetworkCallback()
    val networkRequest = NetworkRequest.Builder()
        .addCapability(NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
        .addTransportType(TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)
        .addTransportType(TRANSPORT_WIFI)
        .addTransportType(TRANSPORT_ETHERNET)
        .build()
    connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(networkRequest, networkCallback)
```

Let's look at `networkRequest`. The network I'm requesting need to have a `NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET` and some transport types which I've specified in the code.
Then I register a network callback. As per docs - `Registers to receive notifications about all networks which satisfy the given NetworkRequest.`

Means, e.g. I'll turn WI-FI on/off, the network callback will fire only if I've specified that transport type or corresponding capabilities inside the network request. Now the question is, when the `networkCallback` triggers, do I need to check for the capabilities and transport types again?

```
override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
        val networkCapabilities = cm.getNetworkCapabilities(network)
        val hasInternetCapabilities = networkCapabilities?.let {
            return@let it.hasCapability(NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET) or
                it.hasTransport(TRANSPORT_WIFI) or
                it.hasTransport(TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) or
                it.hasTransport(TRANSPORT_ETHERNET)
        } ?: false
    }
}
```

As I've understood, if the network will not satisfy my `networkRequest`, the check inside `onAvailable()` is irrelevant because it won't execute. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, the additional check you have in `onAvailable` is unnecessary. The platform will only send `onAvailable` for networks that *satisfy* the passed in `NetworkRequest` (otherwise, the API would be pretty pointless).

Here is some official docs ([link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/reading-network-state#additional-networks)) on the topic:

> The app builds a NetworkRequest to inform ConnectivityManager of what
> kind of networks it wants to listen to. For example, if your app is
> only interested in unmetered internet connections:
>
> ```
> NetworkRequest request = new NetworkRequest.Builder()
>   .addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_METERED)
>   .addCapability(NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
>   .build();
> connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(request, myNetworkCallback);
> ```
>
> This would ensure that your app hears about all
> changes concerning any unmetered network on the system.

**Note the below is accurate at the time of writing this answer.**

For callbacks, in the Connectivity stack in Android they are known as *listen* requests, therefore if you wanted to see how they interplay with sending `onAvailable` it would be [here](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:packages/modules/Connectivity/service/src/com/android/server/ConnectivityService.java?q=notifyNetworkAvailable%5C(nai%5C,%5C%20nri%5C)%5C;%20f:connectivityservice) in `processNewlySatisfiedListenRequests`:

```
private void processNewlySatisfiedListenRequests(@NonNull final NetworkAgentInfo nai) {
        for (final NetworkRequestInfo nri : mNetworkRequests.values()) {
            if (nri.isMultilayerRequest()) {
                continue;
            }
            final NetworkRequest nr = nri.mRequests.get(0);
            if (!nr.isListen()) continue;
            if (nai.satisfies(nr) && !nai.isSatisfyingRequest(nr.requestId)) {
                nai.addRequest(nr);
                notifyNetworkAvailable(nai, nri);
            }
        }
    }
```

`ConnectivityService` which controls all of this is pretty hard to follow, but if you follow the code path that lands here, you'll see it comes from the method `computeNetworkReassignment` [here](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:packages/modules/Connectivity/service/src/com/android/server/ConnectivityService.java?q=NetworkReassignment%5C%20computeNetworkReassignment%20f:connectivityservice).

The important line of code in the above is this:

```
bestNetwork = mNetworkRanker.getBestNetwork(req, nais, nri.getSatisfier());
```

Drilling into that method you'll see that it calls `NetworkRanker` which runs `satisfies` against the originally passed in `NetworkRequest`:

```
final ArrayList<NetworkAgentInfo> candidates = filter(nais, nai -> nai.satisfies(request));
```

Given the above, you can see that if you receive an `onAvailable` for a `NetworkRequest`, it will satisfy whatever the original `NetworkCapabilities` were passed in therefore it isn't necessary to check them again to confirm.